# SQL Server Reporting Services: Generate Scripts Programmatically

Tags: sql-server, scripting, powershell

I'm looking to export SSRS reports from SSRS 2005 into SSRS 2017. I have around 100 reports to move but in total there are around 500 subscriptions across all of these reports.

The `Script to file` tool in SSMS 2005 would save a large amount of time however is there a way to programmatically call the `Script to file` function?

I know you can do something similar with Powershell to export databases.

Comment: There are different ways of migrating your SSRS reports to another one. I wrote this blog that uses the reporting server databases backup and restore to achieve this. Link: https://samosql.com/2017/10/25/migration-of-ssrs-to-another-instance/              Hope that helps and gives you a lead. Let me know of additional questions or concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how well powershell would handle the guids for the reports when you only transfer the jobs, but you could use [rs.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/script-with-the-rs-exe-utility-and-the-web-service?view=sql-server-2017) to execute a script file and call the webservice to download/copy/deploy Reporting Services Objects.

On the [Sample Reporting Services rs.exe Script to Copy Content between Report Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/sample-reporting-services-rs-exe-script-to-copy-content-between-report-servers?view=sql-server-2017) it is stated that Shared Schedules are supported for both native and sharepoint integrated instances.

There used to be a tool called "rsscripter" that provided a gui to create the scripts but I'm not sure how well it will work with more recent versions. It's included in the [SQL Server fine build](https://github.com/SQL-FineBuild/SQL-FineBuild/wiki) and looks like this:

[image]

The original article on that tool can still be found on archive.org [Download Reporting Services Scripter](https://web.archive.org/web/20120830141644/http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=62)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function to facilitate me doing SQL Server Migrations, but it does take the agent jobs on one server and writes them to disk as .sql files.

```
Function Write-SQLAgentJobs([string]$ServerInstance, [string]$ExportPath)
{

    #Create Directory if needed.
    If((Test-Path -LiteralPath $ExportPath -PathType Container) -eq  $false)
    {
        New-Item -Path $ExportPath -ItemType Container | Out-Null 
        Write-Debug -Message "$(Get-Date) - Creating Export Path $($ExportPath)"
    }

    #Get the Additional Modules needed for doing the work.
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null 

    $SMO = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $ServerInstance 

    #Build Up Scripter Object...
    $Scripter = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter') ($SMO)
    $ScriptOptions = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptingOptions')

    $Scripter.Options.ScriptDrops = $False
    $Scripter.Options.WithDependencies = $False
    $Scripter.Options.IncludeHeaders = $True
    $Scripter.Options.AppendToFile = $False
    $Scripter.Options.ToFileOnly = $True
    $Scripter.Options.ClusteredIndexes = $True
    $Scripter.Options.DriAll = $True
    $Scripter.Options.Indexes = $True
    $Scripter.Options.Triggers = $True

    $Scripter.Options = $ScriptOptions

    ForEach($Job In ($SMO.JobServer.Jobs | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.name -ne ""}))
    {

        $JobName = ConvertTo-ValidPath -TestPath ($Job.name)
        $FileName = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($ExportPath, "$($JobName).sql")

        If((Test-Path -LiteralPath $FileName -PathType leaf) -eq $true)
        {
            Remove-Item -LiteralPath $FileName -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
        }

        $Scripter.Options.FileName = $FileName
        $Scripter.Script($Job) | Out-Null 

    }

}

Function ConvertTo-ValidPath([string]$TestPath)
{

    $invalidChars = [IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() -join ''
    $re = "[{0}]" -f [RegEx]::Escape($invalidChars)

    Write-Output ($TestPath -replace $re)

}
```